# How to enhance the performance of nested query?

Tags: sql, performance, t-sql, informix

I have the following query but it run slowly in my `sql editor` !
How to enhance it (write wise) to speed the query running .

---

```
SELECT year,main_code,name,father_code,main_code || '__' || year AS main_id, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM GK_main 
WHERE father_code=sc.main_code AND 
year= (SELECT MAX(year)FROM SS_job)) childcount
FROM GK_main sc WHERE year=(SELECT MAX(year)FROM SS_job)
```

Comment: Since `SELECT max(year) from SS_job` is static, try selecting it into a local variable first and then just reference it. Otherwise you are executing `SELECT max(year) from SS_job` twice for every row in GK_main

Comment: Could u write the query please

Comment: following the DeanOC logic , you can put this select ss_job into the mainly FROM clause :`FROM gk_main sc, (select max(year) from ss_job) as ss_job(year)` , will have the same effect use a external variable where this max will be executed only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The efficiency depends more on available indexes, rather than the way it is written. You could try this version (without inline subqueries):

```
SELECT 
    sc.year,
    sc.main_code,
    sc.name,
    sc.father_code,
    sc.main_code || '__' || sc.year AS main_id, 
    NVL(g.childcount, 0) AS childcount
FROM 
    GK_main sc
  LEFT JOIN
    ( SELECT father_code ,
             COUNT(*) AS childcount
      FROM GK_main 
      WHERE year = (SELECT MAX(year) FROM SS_job)
      GROUP BY father_code
    ) AS g
      ON g.father_code = sc.main_code 
WHERE 
    sc.year = (SELECT MAX(year) FROM SS_job) ;
```

But what would benefit the efficiency would be indexes.

- Is there an index on `SS_job (year)`?
- Is there an index on `GK_main (year, father_code)` or on `GK_main (father_code, year)`?
- Is there an index on `GK_main (year, main_code)` or on `GK_main (main_code)`?

Comment: Great but some records the `childcount` is empty string not `0` !!

Comment: `COALESCE(g.childcount, 0)` CAN'T BE RESOLVED informix .

Comment: You should check which version of Informix you are using and its documentation. Since the standard SQL `COALESCE()` is not supported, either `NVL()` or `DECODE()` function can be used or a `CASE` expression.

Answer (score 1):

Use a join instead of subquery.

```
SELECT sc.year,sc.main_code,sc.name,sc.father_code,sc.main_code || '__' || sc.year AS main_id, 
COUNT(F.father_code) AS childcount
FROM GK_main sc LEFT JOIN GK_main F ON F.father_code = sc.main_code
WHERE year=(SELECT MAX(year)FROM SS_job)
GROUP BY sc.year,sc.main_code,sc.name,sc.father_code
```

Not tested and made it quickly so might contain a mistake. But this should at least save you from checking SELECT MAX(year)FROM SS_job twice.

I would never do COUNT(*), but always chose the collumn(s) I wish to count.

Comment: Why do you think that `COUNT(*)` is less efficient than `COUNT(column)`?

Comment: @ypercude I would take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219843/count-vs-countid-in-sql-server-2005. It explains it better than I can. It has more to do with locks than performance.

Comment: The answer there is on a totally different road, using the system views.

Comment: my previous query get 1067 record ,in the other hand your query get just 640 record !!

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
SELECT 
   year,
   main_code,
   name,
   father_code,
   main_code || '__' || year AS main_id, 
   childcount.cnt as 'count'
FROM 
   GK_main sc 
LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT 
       father_code, 
       COUNT(*) AS cnt 
   FROM 
       GK_main 
   WHERE 
       year= (SELECT MAX(year)FROM SS_job) 
   GROUP BY 
       father_code) childcount
ON childcount.father_code = sc.main_code
```

Create necesary index on `(father_code, year)` that will help

Comment: Incorrect data . my previous query get 1067 record ,in the other hand your query get just `640` record !!